# How to avoid page reloading while switching to other page?

Tags: angularjs

am using AngularJS in my project. In my project I have timeline page which shows all post like Facebook. While seeing my post in timeline continuously and if I go to next tab and come back to timeline page the page get refreshed and it shows the post from the beginning. Can anyone give suggestion to avoid refreshing the page and it should stay on last  post while going to another tab?

Comment: Can you show us snippet of your code? Which tab do you use?

Comment: Some code would be great to understand problem statement.  A tip, however - Controllers are not singletons, providers (services and factories) are singletons. If you do not want re-render; you collect the data on first-page load, use getters and setters in singletons and then use them in your controllers. This way, you can be sure to never have anything re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use $ionicHistory.goBack() (or) window.history.back()

ex:

```
$scope.goBack = function() {
  $window.history.go(-1);
}
```

Or try

```
$window.history.back()
```

Comment: Surjeet Bhadauriya & Dharmarajm 
can you please let me know about this `$ionicHistory.goBack()`
why to use this ?

Comment: @Parth Raval Where I have to include it?

Answer (score 0):

See if you have maybe used "href" anywhere. That causes redirection of pages.